# Error in google maps for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

2 Errors showing in firebug

```
ReferenceError: Gmaps4Rails is not defined

})(Gmaps4Rails);

ReferenceError: Gmaps4RailsGoogle is not defined 

Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.bing" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.mapquest" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.openlayers" %>

<body>   
  <%= yield %>
  <%= yield :scripts %>
</body>
```

propertymap.rb(model)

```
  attr_accessible :title, :place, :prop_details

  acts_as_gmappable #:process_geocoding => false (if custom lang and longi tudes)

  def gmaps4rails_address

    "#{self.title}, #{self.place}"
  end
```

property_map_controller.rb

```
 def index

    @properties = PropertyMap.all
    @json = PropertyMap.all.to_gmaps4rails
  end
```

View

```
  <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

empty box is coming in the view without anything in it

Comment: `gmaps4rails.base` should be included before `gmaps4rails.googlemaps`

Comment: Thank You very much apneadiving. I was struggling arround this problem for more than 3hrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gmaps4rails.base` should be included before `gmaps4rails.googlemaps`